# Conditional navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm following the navigation architecture example from `NowInAndroid` sample code.
I have a login screen and a home screen. By default, the login screen is the start destination, and after the `AuthState` comes from the `ViewModel`, navigation to the main screen takes place.
In the case when the user is already logged in, you need to redirect the user immediately to the main screen after the splash screen.

```
sealed class AuthState {
    object LoggedIn : AuthState()
    object EnterPhone : AuthState()
    object EnterCode : AuthState()
    class EnterPassword(val passwordHint: String) : AuthState()
}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    ...
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<AuthState?>(null)
    val uiState: StateFlow<AuthState?> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    ...
}
```

`NavHost` currently consists of only two destinations.

```
NavHost(
    modifier = modifier,
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Login.route
) {
    loginGraph(
        displayFeatures = displayFeatures,
        navController = navController
    )
    homeGraph(
        displayFeatures = displayFeatures,
        navController = navController
    )
}
```

At the moment I am using this solution:

```
@Composable
fun LoginRoute(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    displayFeatures: List<DisplayFeature>,
    onLoggedIn: () -> Unit
) {
    val loginUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = loginUiState) {
        if (loginUiState == AuthState.LoggedIn) onLoggedIn()
    }

    LoginScreen(
        ...
    )
}
```

But the `LoginScreen` still manages to appear for a couple of seconds before the navigation goes to the `MainScreen`.
Is this a problem of `NavHost` that does not support this type of navigation? Or is my solution not quite right?

Comment: I guess the problem is that it takes some time to get correct value of `uiState`. You are probably reading the auth state from disk somewhere and that will take time. You can use some splash screen as start destination, observe uiState and when you get first non-null value, redirect to login/home.